# Copying list and then looping through first list and extending second list results in issue: Both lists get extended

Tags: python-3.x

The following python 3 code results in the tuple ('bla', 1.0) being added to both list1 and list2. Why? They don't point to the same place in memory.

```
#copy list1 to new list2:
for c in list1:
    list2.append(c)

#loop through list1 and extend list2
>>> for idxc, c in enumerate(list1):
...     for idxsc, sc in enumerate(c):
...             list2[idxc][idxsc].extend([tuple(('bla', 1.0))])
```

Comment: Is `list1` a list of lists?  If so, the interior lists are still going to be the same objects across the two lists containing them.

Comment: "Is my universe a miniverse?" :p

Yes, lis1 is a list of lists. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to make a true copy of a list and all its contents, that will work on nested lists is by making a deep copy:

```
import copy

list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you!